# Heroku custom buildpack fsharp

Tags: heroku, buildpack

When you deploy the https://github.com/SuaveIO/heroku-getting-started example project to Heroku, the correct fsharp buildpack is used (specified in the app.json file). Like so:

```
{
  "name": "Sample Suave web app",
  "description": "Sample single-script Suave web app, deployable to Heroku.",
  "website": "http://suave.io/",
  "repository": "https://github.com/SuaveIO/heroku-getting-started",
  "logo": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SuaveIO/suave/gh-pages/images/logo.gif",
  "env": {
    "BUILDPACK_URL": "https://github.com/SuaveIO/mono-script-buildpack.git"
  }
}
```

However, if you want to deploy directly from github, the custom buildpack isn't used.
The only way to get this running is by manually specifying the BUILPACK_URL config var in the web api of the web app. So, why is this config var specified by the app.json not used? Is there another way of specifying this config var, without having to add this manually to the dashboard -> settings -> config vars of the web app?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using app.json, you can use heroku buildpacks command to set/remove/clear buildpacks. Here is the output of command **heroku buildpacks -h**:

```
buildpacks:add BUILDPACK_URL       #  add new app buildpack, inserting into list of buildpacks if neccessary
buildpacks:clear                   #  clear all buildpacks set on the app
buildpacks:remove [BUILDPACK_URL]  #  remove a buildpack set on the app
buildpacks:set BUILDPACK_URL       #  set new app buildpack, overwriting into list of buildpacks if neccessary
```

The heroku toolbelt can be found here: https://toolbelt.heroku.com

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. However, not quite the answer why the app.json setting is not working. I would like to minimise dependencies on external tools for deployment by third parties.